# Meteor - Script doesn't load Web Audio Buffers properly on refresh / only on certain routes

Tags: meteor, web-audio-api

## https://github.com/futureRobin/meteorAudioIssues

Trying to load audio buffers into memory. When I hit localhost:3000/tides or localhost:3000 it loads my buffers into memory with no problems. When I then click through onto a session e.g. localhost:3000/tides/SOMESESSIONID. the buffers have already loaded from the previous state.

However, when I then refresh the page on  "localhost:3000/tides/SOMESESSIONID" the buffers don't load properly and the console just logs an array of file path names.

Crucial to app functionality. Any help would be great!

### audio.js

```
             //new context for loadKit
             var context = new AudioContext();
             var audioContext = null;
             var scheduleAheadTime = 0;
             var current16thNote = 0;
             var bpm = 140;

             //array of samples to load first. 
             var samplesToLoad = [
                 "ghost_kick.wav", "ghost_snare.wav", "zap.wav", "ghost_knock.wav"
             ];


             //create a class called loadKit for loading the sounds. 
             function loadKit(inputArg) {
                 //get the array of 6 file paths from input. 
                 this.drumPath = inputArg;
             }

             //load prototype runs loadsample function. 
             loadKit.prototype.load = function() {
                 //when we call load, call loadsample 6 times
                 //feed it the id and drumPath index value 
                 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                     this.loadSample(i, this.drumPath[i]);
                 }

             };

             //array to hold the samples in. 
             //now loadKitInstance.kickBuffer will hold the buffer.  
             var buffers = [
                 function(buffer) {
                     this.buffer1 = buffer;
                 },
                 function(buffer) {
                     this.buffer2 = buffer;
                 },
                 function(buffer) {
                     this.buffer3 = buffer;
                 },
                 function(buffer) {
                     this.buffer4 = buffer;
                 },
                 function(buffer) {
                     this.buffer5 = buffer;
                 },
                 function(buffer) {
                     this.buffer6 = buffer;
                 }
             ];


             //load in the samples. 
             loadKit.prototype.loadSample = function(id, url) {
                 //new XML request.
                 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 //load the url & set response to arraybuffer
                 request.open("GET", url, true);
                 request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

                 //save the result to sample
                 var sample = this;



                 //once loaded decode the output & bind to the buffers array
                 request.onload = function() {
                         buffers[id].bind("");
                         context.decodeAudioData(request.response, buffers[id].bind(sample));
                     }
                     //send the request. 
                 request.send();
             };

             //get the list of drums from the beat.json
             //load them into a the var 'loadedkit'.
             loadDrums = function(listOfSamples) {
                 var drums = samplesToLoad;
                 loadedKit = new loadKit(listOfSamples);
                 loadedKit.load();
                 console.log(loadedKit);
             }

             //create a new audio context.
             initContext = function() {
                 try {
                     //create new Audio Context, global.
                     sampleContext = new AudioContext();
                     //create new Tuna instance, global
                     console.log("web audio context loaded");
                 } catch (e) {
                     //if not then alert
                     alert('Sorry, your browser does not support the Web Audio API.');
                 }
             }


             //inital function, ran on window load. 
             init = function() {
                 audioContext = new AudioContext();
                 timerWorker = new Worker("/timer_worker.js");


            }
```

---

### client/main.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        init();
        initContext();
    });
```

---

### router.js

```
Router.route('/', {
        template: 'myTemplate',

        subscriptions: function() {
        this.subscribe('sessions').wait();
      },
       // Subscriptions or other things we want to "wait" on. This also
      // automatically uses the loading hook. That's the only difference between
      // this option and the subscriptions option above.
      waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('sessions');
      },

       // A data function that can be used to automatically set the data context for
      // our layout. This function can also be used by hooks and plugins. For
      // example, the "dataNotFound" plugin calls this function to see if it
      // returns a null value, and if so, renders the not found template.
      data: function () {
        return Sessions.findOne({});
      },

        action: function () {
        loadDrums(["ghost_kick.wav", "ghost_snare.wav", "zap.wav", "ghost_knock.wav"]);
        // render all templates and regions for this route
        this.render();
      }
    });



    Router.route('/tides/:_id',{
        template: 'idTemplate', 
     // a place to put your subscriptions
      subscriptions: function() {
        this.subscribe('sessions', this.params._id).wait();
      },
       // Subscriptions or other things we want to "wait" on. This also
      // automatically uses the loading hook. That's the only difference between
      // this option and the subscriptions option above.
      waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('sessions');
      },

       // A data function that can be used to automatically set the data context for
      // our layout. This function can also be used by hooks and plugins. For
      // example, the "dataNotFound" plugin calls this function to see if it
      // returns a null value, and if so, renders the not found template.
      data: function (params) {
        return Sessions.findOne(this.params._id);
      },

        action: function () {
          console.log("IN ACTION")
          console.log(Sessions.findOne(this.params._id));
          var samples = Sessions.findOne(this.params._id)["sampleList"];
          console.log(samples);
        loadDrums(samples);
        // render all templates and regions for this route
        this.render();
      }
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure all of this code is necessary to understand and reproduce your issue? Please see what is a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i got a reply on the meteor forums!

https://forums.meteor.com/t/script-doesnt-load-web-audio-buffers-properly-on--id-routes/15270

*"it looks like your problem is relative paths, it's trying to load your files from localhost:3000/tides/ghost_*.wav if you change line 58 of your router to go up a directory for each file it should work.*

```
loadDrums(["../ghost_kick.wav", "../ghost_snare.wav", "../zap.wav", "../ghost_knock.wav"]);
```

This did the trick. Seems odd that Meteor can load stuff fine without using '../' in one route but not in another but there we go. Hope this helps someone in the future.